# python redis scan and flush caused lock?

Tags: redis, redis-py

I used redis for synchronize some datas.

**Precondition : Data inserted into redis continuously. (About 30,000 in 10 minutes)**

Here is work flow that execute every 5 minutes.

1. Scan keys by specific pattern(ex. 'users*')
2. Get all values by keys
3. Flush all keys

In workflow 1, I used `scan_iter()` to avoid locking.

I wonder that in my workflow, there is any things to causing redis lock?

If data insertion and scanning keys occur simultaneously, it can cause locking?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the `ASYNC` option then FLUSHDB and FLUSHALL are blocking commands.

https://redis.io/commands/flushall